# ArgumentNullException was unhandled - tried everything

Tags: c#

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Value cannot be null"

I am a begginner

Basically I am trying to edit a saved file but everytime I try it gives me that error depending on what I try to edit.
gravar = save.

txtNome = name.

data = date.

telemovel = cellphone number.

morada = address.

email = email .

dados = data / contacts.

```
        private void gravarToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dados[lista.SelectedIndex, 0] = txtNome.Text;
        dados[lista.SelectedIndex, 1] = data.Text;
        dados[lista.SelectedIndex, 2] = telemovel;
        dados[lista.SelectedIndex, 3] = morada;
        dados[lista.SelectedIndex, 4] = email;

        FileStream fs = new FileStream("Dados.dat", FileMode.Append);

        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            bw.Write(dados[i, 0]);
            bw.Write(dados[i, 1]);
            bw.Write(dados[i, 2]);
            bw.Write(dados[i, 3]);
            bw.Write(dados[i, 4]);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Os dados foram gravados em Dados.dat com sucesso.");

        bw.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Debug your application, find out which line is throwing that exception, then look at the state of your variables and figure this out. Right now, nobody can help as you haven't given enough information.

Comment: View Exception details in debug mode to find out the reason

Answer (score -1):

Where are you getting this logic from:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
```

I would suggest using this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dados.GetLength(0); i++)
```

Comment: Having the improper length wouldn't result in the error the OP has described.